# Angular 17 IDE not recompiling after scss error

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I updated to Angular 17 I'm also using Angular Materials and .scss files for all of my components.
I'm using `ng serve` for development.
The issue is when editing my .scss file, if there was a compilation error it will continue showing the same error even after I fixed the syntax. The result is that I have to close the terminal and run `ng serve` again in order to see my changes.
[image]

I've already updated my `tsconfig.json` to use `"compileOnSave": true,` but the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/26325). It's being [worked on](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/26346).

It should be fixed in an upcomming version.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to have been resolved with the latest update, thank you!